# UWP FolderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync fails with COMException / E_FAIL

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP app I have the following code:

```
private async void testButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
  StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
}
```

but when I run this it fails on the second line with the message `An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in .... but was not handled in user code`.  The HRESULT from the exception is -2147467259 = 0x80004005 = E_FAIL.

I'm using file pickers already elsewhere in the app without problem.  This is running on a Win10 desktop (launched from VS2015).  Can anyone suggest why the error occurs and/or what to do to resolve it?  Having a meaningless error message in what appears to be the simplest code possible I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a bit of an oddity in WinRT. Although it is not mentioned in the documentation explicitly, it is necessary to add at least one item in the `FileTypeFilter` collection:

```
var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

You can use a specific extension like `".jpg"`, but it doesn't seem to have effect in a `FolderPicker` anyway. The only thing that matters is that at least one valid item is present.

Comment: Yikes that's obscure - what a bad error message.  It did indeed solve the problem.

Comment: What a wierd error message, it was imposible to think this could be problem. thanks for ur solution.