# Invalid XML manifest with broadFileSystemAccess

Tags: uwp

I followed [this official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities) to add

```
<Package xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap">
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

to my app's manifest. But Visual Studio complains that the resulting XML is invalid: It doesn't expect any `rescap:Capability` in `Capabilities`. (I am using Visual Studio 15.7.1 and Windows SDK 17134.)

How to successfully add the declaration?

EDIT: Here is the screenshot:

[image: Restricted Capability invalid element]

Comment: Have you figured it out yet? Because I'm facing the same problem. MS docs guides towards this error.

Comment: Yes, it works. Just follow @SunteenWu's answer below. You may need to clean up the solution.

Comment: You were kinda right. Turns out I needed to add a type filter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178567/uwp-folderpicker-picksinglefolderasync-fails-with-comexception-e-fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the official mentioned, to use the `xmlns:rescap` namespace restricted capabilities must include the `rescap` namespace. But `uap5` is no needed  for ignoring which you put in your code. So that try to update your code as follows:

```
<Package xmlns:rescap="..." IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

If you also need to ignore the `uap5` namespace, you should also have `uap5` namespace referenced, for example,

```
<Package
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
xmlns:uap5=" http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap" >
```

Comment: I put what you suggested but there is still error and the app cannot be packaged. Please see the screenshot I added to the question.

Comment: @AnHoa, try clean and rebuild your solution. If still have issues, create a blank UWP app and update the manifest as I showed. If still have issues, upload the whole `package.manifest`.

Comment: @AnHoa MSFT dropped the ball with UWP.  There is no way to access files without using their API. So forget about memory mapped files. And local TCP servers will give you plenty of trouble too.  I believe rescap may be limited to partners.  But of course that is no where to be seen on their site. Learned that from someone else's comments.

Comment: @BAR `broadFileSystemAccess` is actually available to every developers (you just need to tell them what you intend to do with it during app submission). And yes, it's only available via `StorageFile` API but that's all I need for this one app.